# jQuery doesn't display images on mobile

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm making a web app in php where you submit pictures in one file and display them in another file. To handle when people upload multiple files to the same team I wanted to create an image gallery, but I save the pictures in their binary form in txt files so I don't have to deal with the file extensions when I'm displaying them. I decided to use jQuery and AJAX to it by displaying an image then when you click on some text it goes to the next one. Everything works perfectly on my computer where I'm using chrome, but when I try and do it on mobile (specifically chrome and safari on ios) the picture doesn't load. does anyone know what could be causing this? Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Yeti Robotics Scouting</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<link href="scouting.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scouting.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
    <nav>
        <a href="/">Yeti Scouting</a> | 
        <a href="/results.php">Results</a> | 
        <a href="/pit.php">Pit Form</a>
        <form class="search" action="team.php" method="get">
            <input type="number" name="team" placeholder="Enter team number" />
            <button type="submit">Go</button>
        </form>
        </nav>
        <hr />
    </div>
<script>
    var picNum = 1; 
    var teamNumber = <?php echo json_encode($_GET['teamNumber']);?>;
    var picLimit = <?php 
        for($i = 1; file_exists("pics/" . $_GET['teamNumber'] . "/" . $i . ".txt"); $i++){}
        echo json_encode($i - 1);?>;

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.get("get_picture.php?teamNumber=" + teamNumber + "&pic=1", function(data, status) {
            $("#picture").attr("src", data);
        });
        refreshPicNum();
    });

    function previousPicture() {
        if (picNum > 1) {
            picNum--;
        } else {
            picNum = picLimit;
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.get("get_picture.php?teamNumber=" + teamNumber + "&pic=" + picNum, function(data, status) {
                $("#picture").attr("src", data);
            });
        });
        refreshPicNum();
    }

    function nextPicture() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            if (picNum < picLimit) {
                picNum++;
            } else {
                picNum = 1;
            }
            $.get("get_picture.php?teamNumber=" + teamNumber + "&pic=" + picNum, function(data, status) {
                $("#picture").attr("src", data);
            });
        });
        refreshPicNum();
    };

    function refreshPicNum() {
        document.getElementById("pic_num").innerHTML = picNum + "/" + picLimit;
    }
</script>
<center><span id='pic_num'></span></center>
<span class='left_arrow' onclick="previousPicture()">
    ← Previous Picture
</span>
<span class='right_arrow'onclick="nextPicture()">
    Next Picture →
</span>
<img id='picture' src='' alt='What? No picture?!?'>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: So it appears that for whatever reason the page works on safari, however it still displays the alt of the img in chrome.

Comment: Are these really large pics, or are there many of them? What format are the images?

Comment: @braks The pictures are intended to be taken with phone camera and the only phone I can test it with is an iPhone 6 which has an 8 megapixel camera and the size of the txt files the pictures are saved as is between 1,545 KB and 2,119 KB.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like iOS Chrome just can't do jQuery for some reason, must have something to do with how apple treats third party browsers.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible you've hit some of the iOS Resource Limits

> Because of the memory available on iOS, there are limits on the number
>   of resources it can process:
>
> The maximum size for decoded GIF, PNG, and TIFF images is 3 megapixels
>   for devices with less than 256 MB RAM and 5 megapixels for devices
>   with greater or equal than 256 MB RAM. That is, ensure that width *
>   height ≤ 3 * 1024 * 1024 for devices with less than 256 MB RAM. Note
>   that the decoded size is far larger than the encoded size of an image.
>
> The maximum decoded image size for JPEG is 32 megapixels using
>   subsampling. JPEG images can be up to 32 megapixels due to
>   subsampling, which allows JPEG images to decode to a size that has one
>   sixteenth the number of pixels. JPEG images larger than 2 megapixels
>   are subsampled—that is, decoded to a reduced size. JPEG subsampling
>   allows the user to view images from the latest digital cameras.
>
> The maximum size for a canvas element is 3 megapixels for devices with
>   less than 256 MB RAM and 5 megapixels for devices with greater or
>   equal than 256 MB RAM. The height and width of a canvas object is 150
>   x 300 pixels if not specified.
>
> JavaScript execution time is limited to 10 seconds for each top-level
>   entry point. If your script executes for more than 10 seconds, Safari
>   on iOS stops executing the script at a random place in your code, so
>   unintended consequences may result.
>
> This limit is imposed because JavaScript execution may cause the main
>   thread to block, so when scripts are running, the user is not able to
>   interact with the webpage.
>
> See the Safari Web Inspector Guide for how to debug JavaScript on iOS.
>
> The maximum number of documents that can be open at once is eight on
>   iPhone and nine on iPad. iOS Note: In iOS 1.1.4 and earlier, the
>   JavaScript execution time was limited to 5 seconds and the size of
>   allocations to 10 MB. Also, the limit on the size of canvas elements
>   was the same as Safari on the desktop. In iOS 2.2.1 and earlier, the
>   sum of all of the frames needs to be less than 2 megapixels—that is,
>   width * height * number of frames ≤ 2 * 1024 * 1024. In iOS 3.0 and
>   later, the limit only applies to one frame at a time. You also need to
>   size images appropriately. Don’t rely on browser scaling. For example,
>   don’t put a 100 x 100 image in a 10 x 10  element. Tile small
>   backgrounds images; don’t use large background images.

That's just some of it, refer to this for more information:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html

Comment: it's very unlikely the pictures will be anything but a jpg and even less likely they will be more than 32 megapixels. Is it possible that ios chrome and safari can't handle an img tag with a src that's in binary?